# SwiftUI - Timer doesn't stop at 0

Tags: ios, swift, timer, swiftui, countdown

I have a timer that counts down from a specific day to the current date
but the problem I'm facing is that the timer doesn't stop when it reaches 00:00:00

I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/better-programming/make-a-simple-countdown-with-timer-and-swiftui-3ce355b54986)

```
@State var currentDate: Date = Date()
var timer: Timer {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (_) in
        self.currentDate = Date()
    }
}

var endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 1, to: Date())!

var body: some View {
    Text(countdownString(to: endDate))
        .font(.headline)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .foregroundColor(.green)
        .onAppear {
            _ = self.timer
            if self.endDate == self.currentDate {
                self.timer.invalidate()
            }
    }
}



func countdownString(to date: Date) -> String {
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: currentDate, to: endDate)
    return String(format: "%02d hours : %02d minutes : %02d seconds",
                  components.hour ?? 00,
                  components.minute ?? 00,
                  components.second ?? 00)
}
```

Comment: invalidate timer when time is up and don't use repeated timer if you just need only one countdown. you simulate a runloop.. which is not wrong but in .onAppear {.. } you will want to check if time is up and not call timer again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the timer in the `onAppear` and invalidate the `timer` when `endDate` and `currentDate` align together.

```
struct CV: View {
    @State var currentDate: Date = Date()
    @State var timer: Timer?

    var endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 1, to: Date())!

    var body: some View {
        Text(countdownString(to: endDate))
            .font(.headline)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .onAppear {
                self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
                    self.currentDate = Date()
                }
        }
    }

    func countdownString(to date: Date) -> String {
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: currentDate, to: endDate)
        if currentDate >= endDate {
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = nil
        }
        return String(format: "%02d hours : %02d minutes : %02d seconds",
                      components.hour ?? 00,
                      components.minute ?? 00,
                      components.second ?? 00)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why this worked but not my code? (I edited it and added timer.invalidate)

Comment: @L.Sherbini You have make the timer a state property not a computed property as you did.